# Tracking who is using my App

Tags: android

I have launched an app named Salefee. In this app, basically I am compiling all the products in all the stores of different brand. User will be able to see the product/dress available around him. He can then go to store and then purchase item from the store which he saw on App. I want to track users who used my app and then went to store to purchase it.

Step 1
Uses our Platform to check information in store

Step 2
Visit the store

Step 3
Purchase the product

Step 4
Come Home

In step 3, How can we track that the person is purchasing through Salefee ? or What should a person must do so that Salefee would know that the transaction has happened through it ?

What feature should I add in my app so that I can track users who used my app to purchase stuff through stores.

App link:https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.salefee.salefee.salefee

Thanks In advance!!

Comment: Did you consider google analytics for your app? It includes functionality that allows you to know which screens are being used, you can track user actions, etc.

Comment: I want to know who actually used my app and went to store to buy it..n not just who used my app to surf the products.

Comment: The analytics will tell you who went to your shopping screen. If what you want to measure is the traffic the app is sending to your web store then I think you can use cohorts and track those visits in your store page,  assuming you are using google analytics there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previous users said you need Google Analytics which provde actions. Just put action trigger in your onclicklistener( on your buy button in store). What this does is sends event to your analytics account with all information of user under action, and you can send your own data in action like userid, phone model, name etc. Example of trigger from official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events#overview)

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Build and send an Event.
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory(getString(categoryId))
    .setAction(getString(actionId))
    .setLabel(getString(labelId))
    .build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flurry or google analytics to track all activities by user. By using google analytics you will be able to track how many users are online according to page number also.

Comment: I want to know who actually used my app and went to store to buy it..n not just who used my app to surf the products.

Comment: Then you need to implement your own analytics. So At any action point you need to log data to your server, so you can find out all analytics as per your custom requirements.